# How to compile application.js file in webpacker rails 6

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I just upgraded my rails 4 app to rails 6. After installing webpacker gem and moving all js files from assets to app/javascript folder and compiling assets when i hit request on browser i got this error.

**ActionView::Template::Error The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.**

Anyone can tell that what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use new view helper

`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

in layouts/application.html.erb.
Make sure your javascript folder structure should be like this.

- app

  - javascript

    - images
    - packs

      - application.js
    - stylesheets